# React Native Android Text colour not working (except Black and White)

Tags: android, react-native

I'm building an android app using React Native, but I have problem when it comes to setting the Text colour. I cannot seem to use other colour than Black or White. For example; using

```
<Text style={{color: '#ff0000'}}>Read Notice Here</Text>
```

would cause the text to be Black colour instead of Red. I have used React Native to build app for iOS and changing the colour like this works there, but somehow not on Android. I've checked the documentation but didn't see any mentions on limitation either. Is there a certain settings that I have to set first before being able to set text colour on Android?

I've tried stripping everything to just a basic class but still doesn't seem to work:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

export default class StartScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <Text style={{color: '#F00'}}>TEST</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Android version: 5.1
React-Native version: 0.46.1

**EDIT:**

It seems that React-Native page actually have a line that states:

> Android Studio installs the latest Android SDK by default. Building a
>   React Native app with native code, however, requires the Android 6.0
>   (Marshmallow) SDK in particular

Since my device was running Android 5.1. It caused issues like this one.

source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: does specifying a color, eg `color: 'red'` work?

Comment: @RyanTurnbull tried that, unfortunately it didn't worked either.

Comment: maybe can you show me your full code? i think the color not changed because there are something triger which it make not changed.

Comment: i have tried your code, and work well in my device

Comment: @muhammadaa I've added a basic class that I tried into the question. However even when there's no other element in the render(), the problem still the same.

Comment: @RizalSidik this could be a device issue then? Mind me asking; what's your device and react-native version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to change its android version ?

I worked on version android 6.0, your code is work..i think the problem on your version android.

[image]

*Edit*#1

I read on documentation [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). They suggest to require the **Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)** when we use ReactNative.

Comment: Yes, turns out it is an android version issue. I tried running it on an emulator with Marshmallow OS, and the colours displayed like it should. Unfortunately, I can't seem to understand why the android version would cause this issue though....

Comment: i think minimun requirement for `react-native` is Marshmallow OS. you can read documentation in [getting started with ReactNative](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). In section install the SDK Android, they suggest to require the **Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)**. maybe i help you.. keep coding!

Comment: Ah, that seems to be it. I seems to have missed reading that.

Comment: i glad to help you... yeah.. let's have fun, bro @rabbit87. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know there's already an accepted answer here, but in case someone else on react-native^0.57 finds this. . . this was the issue in my case; using textTransform breaks text styling for android. It will make your text disappear, but then if you give it lineHeight you will see it in black only -- and then maybe you'll wind up here. Issue link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21966

Comment: thank you, this was my problem. I actually had a styled text component with text transform set to none and it still caused this issue